# Kalman Filter : How measurement noise covariance matrix and process noise helps in working of kalman filter , can some one explain intuitively?

Tags: filtering, signal-processing, noise, kalman-filter

1. How process noise covariance and measurement noise covariance are helping better functioning of Kalman filter ?
2. Can someone explain intuitively without significant equations and math please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, its difficult to explain mathematical things (like kalman filters) without mathematics, but here's my attempt:

There are two parts to a kalman filter, a time update part and a measurement part. In the time update part we estimate the state at the time of observation; in the measurement part we combine (via least squares) our 'predictions' (ie the estimate from the time update) with the measurements to get a new estimate of the state.

So far, no mention of noise. There are two sources of noise: one in the time update part (sometimes called process noise) and one in the measurement part (observation noise). In each case what we need is a measure of the 'size' of that noise, ie the covariance matrix. These are used when we combine the
predictions with the measurements. When we view our predictions as very uncertain (that is, they have a large covariance matrix) the combination will be closer to the measurements than to the predictions; on the other hand when we view our predictions as very good (small covariance) the combination will be closer to the predictions than to the measurements.

So you could look upon the process and observation noise covariances as saying how much to trust the (parts of) the predictions and observations. Increasing, say, the variance of a particular component of the predictions is to say: trust this prediction less; while increasing the variance of a particular measurement is to say: trust this measurement less. This is mostly an analogy but it can be made more precise. A simple case is when the covariance matrices are diagonal. In that case the cost, ie the contrinution to what we are trying to minimise, of a difference between an measurement and the computed value is te square of that difference, divided by the observations variance. So the higher an observations variance, the lower the cost.

Note that out of the measurement part we also get a new state covariance matrix; this is used (along with the process noise and the dynamics) in the next time update when we compute the predicted state covariance.

I think the question of why the covariance is the appropriate measure of the size of the noise is rather a deep one, as is why least squares is the appropriate way to combine the predictions and the measurements. The shallow answer is that kalman filtering and least squares have been found, over decades (centuries in the case of least squares), to work well in many application areas. In the case of kalman filtering I find the derivation of it from hidden markobv models (From Hidden Markov Models to Linear Dynamical Systems by T.Minka, though this is rather mathematical) convincing. In Hidden markov models we seek to find the (conditional) probability of the states given the measurements so far; Minka shows that if the measurements are linear functions of the states and the dynamics are linear and all probability distributions are Gaussian, then we get the kalman filter.

Comment: Excellent non mathematical explanation. You said "In each case what we need is a measure of the 'size' of that noise, ie the covariance matrix." 
1. Can you please elaborate why size of that noise is covariance matrix ?

In second part you said "Increasing, say, the variance of a particular component of the predictions is to say: trust this prediction less; while increasing the variance of a particular measurement is to say: trust this measurement less."

2. Why did you say increase in variance of prediction or measurement is to trust them less ?
3 How variance is related to trust ?